# Heatmap in R Studio using ggmap and ggplot2 - discrete value applied to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to do a heatmap in R Studio on lon / lat of houses based on their selling prices.

This is how my data looks like:

```
> head(data)
  SellPrice longitude lattitude
1    577401 -111.9373 33.412658
2    586708 -111.7429 33.391641
3    534415 -111.7474 33.460230
4    634607 -112.0530 33.607888
5    489025 -112.0535 33.522867
6    593311 -112.0591 33.521361
```

And this is how I tried to show it:

```
map <- get_map(location='united states', zoom=4, maptype = 'terrain', source='google', color='color')

ggmap(map) + geom_point(
  aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, colour=SellPrice), data=data, alpha=.5 ) +
  scale_color_gradient(low="beige", high="red")
```

However, it tells me this:

```
 Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

Any idea what I am missing? I am really new to RStudio and statistics in general.

Later Edit:

Even if I just leave this part, it still doesn't work, same error:

```
ggmap(map) + geom_point(
  aes(x=longitude, y=lattitude), data=data, alpha=.5 )
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the same since even if I remove the color tag, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it. Just had to make my lat / long numeric values, they were integer

Comment: How could they be integers when they have points past the decimal in your sample data?